# How find this $\ker\sigma_{A}\cap \operatorname{Im}\sigma_{A}$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let $A$ be a matrix of order $n$ over a field $F$. Let the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F$, and let $M_{n}(F)$ be the set of $n$ order complex matrices over $F$.**

> (1):prove the matrix $A$ is invertible

**This aswer I can prove it.**

> (2)Let $\sigma_{A}$ be a linear transformation in $M_{n}(F)$, such that
>   $$\sigma_{A}(X)=A^{-1}X-XA^{-1},\forall X \in M_{n}(F)$$
>   Find $$\ker\sigma_{A}\cap \operatorname{Im}\sigma_{A}$$

My try: I can only prove this if the matrix $A$ is invertible. Thank you for you help.

Comment: From the text it seems that $A$ *must* be invertible, or you can't define $\sigma_A$. Please let me know if my edit didn't change your question.

Comment: The transformation $\sigma_A $ is defined only when $ A $ is invertible. How can you use the fact that the characteristic polynomial of $ A $ is irreducible for that purpose?

Comment: Hello,this problem have two question:(1):prove $A$ is inverible.

Comment: Why do you write with bold? egreg removed the blods in the first formulation and then you added them back...

Answer (score 3):

Characteristic polynomial is irreducible implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct (and not contained in $F$). Changing $A$ by a conjugate we may assume that $A$ is diagonal over an extension of $F$. In that case the kernel of the map $\sigma_{A}$ is the set of all commuting matrices and they are only the diagonal ones.
The image of $\sigma_{A}$ have trace zero. Thus the required intersection is any diagonal matrix with trace zero.

Answer (score 1):

(1) A polynomial without independent term is certainly reducible. Since the characteristic polynomial is irreducible, it must have a non-zero independent term. This means that $\det A$ is not zero and so $A$ is invertible.

(2) Since the characteristic polynomial is irreducible, it must coincide with the minimal polynomial. In this case, every matrix that commutes with $A$ must be a polynomial in $A$ (see for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57308/commutation-when-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomial-agree)).

If $X\in \ker \sigma_A$ then $X$ commutes with $A$ and so is a polynomial in $A$.

I don't know right now what to make of  $X\in \operatorname{im} \sigma_A$.