# I have to show $A$ is not cyclic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose that $A=C\oplus C=\begin{pmatrix} C & 0 \\ 0& C \end{pmatrix}$, $C$ be a  companion matrix of $m(x)=m_0+m_1x+\ldots+m_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$ . I have to show that $A$ is not cyclic. Can any one help?

Comment: Could you explain the definition of  "$A$ is  cyclic"

Comment: a matrix
$A\in Mn(F)$ is called cyclic if there is a vector $t \in M_{n\times 1}(F)$ such that $\{\alpha, \alpha A, . . . , \alpha A^{n−1}\}$ is
a basis for $M_{1×n}(F)$ as a left vector space over $F$.

Answer (score 1):

A space is cyclic with respect to a linear transformation $T$ iff the minimal polynomial of $T$ coincides with its characteristic polynomial.

The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m$ but its characteristic polynomial is $m^2$. Since they are different, $A$ is not cyclic.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035393/minimal-polynomials-and-cyclic-subspaces.

Comment: thanke you lhf. Can you explain more why  the minimal polynomial of A  is m, please.

Comment: @q1000, $m$ is the minimal polynomial of $C$ and so $m(A)=0$. You just need this to know that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is different from its characteristic polynomial.