# Converting a monic polynomial of degree $n$ to its companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, characteristic-polynomial, companion-matrices

Given a polynomial of form $$p_A = t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$$ How can construct the companion matrix $A$ such that $\det(A-tI) = p_A$ **assuming** that you don't already know how $A$ should look like?.

I know that you can prove by induction that $\det(A-tI) = p_A$ if $A$ takes on the following form

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}      
        0      & \cdots & 0      & -a_0    \\
        1      & \cdots & 0      & -a_1    \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
        0      & \cdots & 1      & -a_{n-1}
       \end{pmatrix} $$

But how do you prove the reverse order?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? There are other possible matrices $A$, but this one is nice. So $A$ is not unique here and "reverse order" is not well-defined.

Comment: Well, because I was reading an article where it was given as a definition. I have been questioning the uniqueness (It has be more than just a definition right?).

Comment: Yes, there are several matrices with the same characteristic polynomial. For example, if the are conjugated.

Comment: Try to convert the $n$-th order linear ODE with (constant) coefficients $1, a_{n-1}, \dots, a_0$ into $n$ coupled 1st order ODEs.

Comment: Yes I think that will certainly work. Thank you! @RodrigodeAzevedo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural motivation that I have seen for the companion matrix is that given in Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*. I'll try to present it here so that it can be understood with minimal exposure to abstract algebra.

Given a polynomial of the form
$$
p(t) = t^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 t + a_0,
$$
and a field $\Bbb F$ of scalars, we can define the following $\Bbb F$-algebra associated with this polynomial. We define $V$ to be the [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) $V = \Bbb F[t]/\langle p(t)\rangle$. That is, $V$ consists of formal polynomials over $t$ subject to the rule that $p(t) = 0$ (as a classic example, $\Bbb R[t]/\langle t^2 + 1\rangle$ is one way of presenting the complex numbers). [By polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), we can see that this vector space has dimension $n$. In particular, every polynomial in this vector space can be written in the form $b_{n-1}t^{n-1} + \cdots + b_1 t + b_0$, which means that the set $\mathcal B = \{1,t,\dots,t^{n-1}\}$ forms a basis of this vector space.  We now consider the linear map $\mu:V \to V$ given by $\mu(p(t)) = tp(t)$.

What's interesting about this linear map is that it has the desired minimal and characteristic polynomial. For any polynomial $q$, we see that
$$
q(\mu)(p(t)) = q(t)p(t).
$$
For any polynomial $q$ of degree $n-1$ or smaller, we have $q(\mu)(1) \neq 0$. On the other hand, the rule that $p(t) = 0$ means that $p(\mu)$ multiplies polynomials by $p(t)$, which is equal to $0$, and is thus the zero map. Because the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial and $\mu$ is an operator on a dimension $n$ vector space, $p$ must also be the characteristic polynomial.

With all that said, we want to find the matrix of $\mu$ with respect to $\mathcal B$. It's easy to determine the first $n-1$ columns: for each $i = 0,\dots,n-2$, we have
$$
\mu(t^i) = t^{i+1} \implies [\mu]_{\mathcal B} = 
\pmatrix{0      & \cdots & 0      & ?    \\
        1      & \cdots & 0      & ?    \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
        0      & \cdots & 1      & ?}.
$$
However, $\mu(t^{n-1}) = t^{n}$ does not appear in our list of basis vectors. In order to express $t^n$ as a linear combination of our basis, we use the fact that $p(t) = 0$ to get
$$
t^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 t + a_0 = 0 \implies\\
t^n = -a_0 - a_1t - \cdots - a_{n-1}t^{n-1}.
$$
With that, we can see that the matrix of $\mu$ relative to our basis is given by
$$
C_p = [\mu]_B = \pmatrix{0      & \cdots & 0      & -a_0    \\
        1      & \cdots & 0      & -a_1    \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
        0      & \cdots & 1      & -a_{n-1}}.
$$
So, just like our linear operator $\mu$, the companion matrix $C_p$ will have the desired minimal and characteristic polynomials.

---

If this approach is hard to follow, a similar construction using "cyclic vectors" is presented in Hoffmann and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*.

One way to ensure that $A$ has the desired minimal polynomial is to assert that there is an associated [cyclic vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace). That is, there is a vector $v_0 \in \Bbb F^n$ such that the vectors $\{v_0,Av_0,A^2 v_0,\dots\}$ span $\Bbb F^n$ (as it turns out, every operator over $\Bbb F^n$ with minimal polynomial $p$ [has a cyclic vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035393/minimal-polynomials-and-cyclic-subspaces)). As a consequence of the fact that $v_0$ is a cyclic vector, we see that every vector $v \in \Bbb F^n$ can be written in the form
$$
v = b_0 v_0 + b_1 A v_0 + \cdots + b_d A^d v_0
= (b_0 I + b_1 A + \cdots + b_d A^d) v_0
= q(A) v_0,
$$
where $q(t) = b_0 + b_1t + \cdots + b_d t^d$. Consequently, it must be the case that the vectors $v_0,Av_0,\dots,A^{n-1}v_0$ are linearly independent (this fact is a bit trickier than it seems; if there's interest I can provide a proof).

Now, we consider the matrix of $A$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{v_0,Av_0,\dots,A^{n-1}v_0\}$. It is easy to see that
$$
A(A^iv_0) = A^{i+1}v_0 \quad i = 0,\dots,n-2,
$$
and that
$$
p(A)v_0 = 0 \implies A^n v_0 = -a_0 v_0 - a_1 Av_0 - \cdots - a_{n-1}A^{n-1}v.
$$
With that, we conclude that the matrix of $A$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is, once again, the companion matrix of $p$.