# Property of all commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Given some matrix A, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$

Find all matrices B, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$, such that

$AB =BA$

I found an interesting way to solve this problem, and I want to ask you all is this is a valid solution.

First define any infinite sequence of coefficients $\alpha_k$ where k is an integer such that $k\geq0$. Then write B as the following.

$
B = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k A^k
$

It is easy to prove that B will always commute with A.

$
AB = 
A\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k A^k =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k A^{k+1} =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k A^k A =
BA
$

Can all matrices $B$ that commute with $A$ be represented in this way, or is this a special case that is not true of all matrices B that commute with A?

Comment: See this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3626308/721644) where I gave [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478849/721644) as well. You can also see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices).

Comment: In the second link, you'll see the same property matrices could satisfy, in the comment by Jyrki Lahtonen. Please, search the site before posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When will $AB=BA$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478849/when-will-ab-ba)

Comment: This hardly qualifies as a duplicate since it is only mentioned in a comment on the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For example, if $A=0$ or $A$ is the identity then you only get constant multiples of the identity from this construction, but every matrix commutes with $A$.