# Square root of Matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 \\ 3&4 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, radicals

Find Square root of Matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 \\   3&4  \end{bmatrix}$ without using concept of Eigen Values and Eigen Vectors

I assumed its square root as $$B=\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\   c&d  \end{bmatrix}$$

hence

$$B^2=A$$ $\implies$

$$\begin{bmatrix} a^2+bc &b(a+d) \\   c(a+d)&d^2+bc  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 \\   3&4  \end{bmatrix}$$

So

$$a^2+bc=1 \tag{1}$$

$$b(a+d)=2 \tag{2}$$

$$c(a+d)=3 \tag{3}$$

$$d^2+bc=4 \tag{4}$$  From $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get

$$\frac{b}{c}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Let $b=2k $ and $c=3k$ Then

$$a^2=1-6k^2$$ and $$d^2=4-6k^2$$  So

$$B=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{1-6k^2} &2k\\   3k&\sqrt{4-6k^2}  \end{bmatrix}$$

So

$$B^2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2k \left(\sqrt{1-6k^2}+\sqrt{4-6k^2}\right) \\   3k \left(\sqrt{1-6k^2}+\sqrt{4-6k^2}\right)&4  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 \\   3&4  \end{bmatrix}$$

Now we have to solve for $k$ using equation

$$ \left(\sqrt{1-6k^2}+\sqrt{4-6k^2}\right)=\frac{1}{k} \tag{5}$$ Also

$$\left(\sqrt{1-6k^2}+\sqrt{4-6k^2}\right) \times \left(\sqrt{4-6k^2}-\sqrt{1-6k^2}\right)=3$$ So from $(5)$

$$\left(\sqrt{4-6k^2}-\sqrt{1-6k^2}\right)=3k \tag{6}$$

Subtracting $(6)$ from $(5)$ we get

$$2\sqrt{1-6k^2}=\frac{1}{k}-3k$$  Squaring Both sides we get

$$33k^4-10k^2+1=0$$ we get

$$k^2=\frac{5 \pm i \sqrt{8}}{33}$$ From this we get $k$. is there any other simpler way to find ?

Comment: I think this is the way to go.

Comment: @Umesh shankar Although the solution is quite long, many of the techniques are actually quite common. For example, variable substitution and polynomial factorisation are commonly used as 'standard techniques' (in my opinion) in algebra. I think that the entire proof is quite fluid and understandable - nice job on your proof!

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Eliminate $bc$ from the first equation (the uppercase letters are the RHS),

$$a^2+\frac{BC}{(a+d)^2}=A,$$ and from the first and the last, $$d^2-a^2=D-A.$$

Let $p:=(d+a)/2,m:=(d-a)/2$, giving

$$(p-m)^2+\frac{BC}{4p^2}=A,\\mp=4(D-A)$$

and multiplying by $4p^2$,

$$4(p^2-mp)^2+BC=4(p^2-4(D-A))^2+BC=4Ap^2.$$

This biquadratic equation will give the values of $p$, then $m, a$ and $d$, followed by $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust , It is not by taking cognizance of your above algebraic trick that students will understand the intricacies of linear algebra.

Answer (score 2):

@ Umesh shankar, this is exactly what should not be done (if you want to make progress)!!

Note that $A^2=trace(A)A-\det(A)I=5A+2I$. Since $B^2=A$ we deduce that $A,B$ commute and since $A$ is not a scalar matrix, $B$ is in the form $B=aI+bA$. Then $(aI+BA)^2=A$, that is $a^2I+b^2(5A+2I)+2abA=A$, that implies

$$a^2+2b^2=0\;,\;5b^2+2ab=1.$$

We deduce $33b^4-10b^2+1=0$,....... and, finally, the four solutions.

EDIT.

Recall that the determinant and the trace of a matrix do not change after a change of basis.

Proposition 1. If $A\in M_2$ is not a scalar matrix, then $I,A$ is a basis of the vector space $E=\{X|AX=XA\}$.

Proof. With a change of basis, we may assume that $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\1&b\end{pmatrix}$ (there is $u$ s.t. $u,Au$ is a basis). Let $X=\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\z&t\end{pmatrix}$. Then $AX=XA$ is equivalent to $y=az,x+bz=t$, that is $2$ linear independent linear relations; thus $dim(E)=4-2=2$.

Proposition 2. If $A\in M_2$ is not a scalar matrix, then $A^2=trace(A)A-\det(A)I$.

Proof. As above, we may assume that $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\1&b\end{pmatrix}$.
$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}a&ab\\b&a+b^2\end{pmatrix}=bA+aI=trace(A)A-\det(A)I$.

Answer (score 2):

Just variation of the loup blanc's answer...

Interesting it would be also to check whether it is   possible to use

$B^2-\text{trace}(B)B+\det(B)I=0$ ?

Indeed
$B^2+\det(B)I= A\pm\sqrt{\det(A)}I=\text{trace}(B)B=tB $

If we name $  C=A\pm\sqrt{\det(A)}I$ ( $C$ can be directly calculated) then $\text{trace}(C/t)=t$,  hence
$t^2=\text{trace}(C )$.

Also $4$ solutions.

Comment: Very clever; moreover t≠0 because A is not a scalar matrix. Your solution is the best one.

Comment: @loupblanc I was inspired by your application of the use of Cayley-Hamilton theorem. It seems that it is very suitable for finding a square root of two dimensional matrix - maybe it has some limitations but if a square root  is a real one calculations are very fast - I  checked it on two examples and  got four proper solutions. The case presented in the question gives complex solutions so calculations are a little more complicated..

Answer (score 2):

Square roots suck, so I'll do this with polynomials instead. Any matrix $B$ with $B^2=A$ must commute with $A$. Since there exist vectors $e$ such that $(e,Ae)$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^2$ (in fact the first standard basis vector will do, as will almost any other vector), any matrix commuting with $A$ must be a polynomial in$~A$, as shown for instance elementarily in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57311/18880).

Since $A^2=2I_2+5A$ (check it) any polynomial in$~A$ can be rewritten to a polynomial of degree${}<2$ in$~A$. So let $B=sI_2+tA$ then $B^2=s^2I_2+2stA+t^2A^2=(s^2+2t^2)I_2+(2st+5t^2)A$. You need that to be equal to $A$ and since $I_2$ and $A$ are linearly independent, it will hold if and only if $s^2+2t^2=0$ and $2st+5t^2=1$. Clearly there are no solutions over $\Bbb R$, so if the question was to find a real square root of$~A$, the answer is there are none.

Working over the complex numbers, we can however continue. We must have $t\neq0$, and then the first equation says $(s/t)^2=-2$. First take $s/t=\sqrt2\,\mathbf i$, then the second equation becomes $\sqrt8\,\mathbf it^2+5t^2=1$ or $t^2=\frac{5-\sqrt8\,\mathbf i}{33}$. Taking complex square roots gives you two solutions. Taking instead $s/t=-\sqrt2\,\mathbf i$ one gets $t^2=\frac{5+\sqrt8\,\mathbf i}{33}$ with again two solutions. These appear to be the ones you found in the question. I don't think it will clarify anything to detail these solutions any further (it just becomes a mess, though it will work if you persevere).